# Parameterization of a cylinder

Tags: integration

I have to calculate the volume of a cylinder $x^2+y^2=9$ bounded by the $XY$ plane and the plane $y + z = 4$.

I have used cylindrical coordinates:
$x= r cos(\alpha)$
$y= r sin(\alpha)$
$z=t$

for $r \in [0,3]$, $\alpha \in [0,2 \pi]$ and $t \in [0, 4-r sin(\alpha)]$

I have a serious doubt about whether the parameterization is good (especially the limits).Are they well calculated?

Comment: @Catcroker If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

As **final check** note that for for symmetry the volume should be equal to the base area 
 (=$9\pi$) times the average height under the plane(=4).

Answer (score 1):

Looks good!

To calculate the volume with an integral in cylindrical coordinates, be careful that you don't forget that (with your convention of the coordinates) $\mbox{d}x\,\mbox{d}y\,\mbox{d}z \to r\,\mbox{d}r\,\mbox{d}\alpha\,\mbox{d}t$.